# Friction costs of storing data in a second smart contract

Tags: gas, gas-estimate, out-of-gas

Whats the difference in terms of Gas of the two Scenarios described below?

- How much are the friction costs of storing data in a second contract compared to storing the number in the contract in which the function is executed?
- Are there any disadvantages of reading data from a second contract compared to reading a variable that is stored in the function's contract?

**Scenario 1**

```
Contract A

function storeNumber(uint256 number){
storedNumber=number;
}
```

**Scenario 2**

```
Contract A
function storeNumber(uint256 number){
ContractB.storeNumber_(uint256 number)
}

Contract B
function storeNumber_(uint256 number){
storedNumber=number;
}
```

Thx